# While transforming xml to html using xsl and java, I need to use style attribute(inline style) with xml element value

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have the requirement in below way .I need XMl element for xslt table inline style.Please check the below code.

### XML pseudo code:

This is the xml code which contains the following data

```
            <xml>
            <event>
            <message>
            This is message
            </message>
            <color>
            #66666
            </color>
            </event>
```

### XSLT CODE:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

            <xsl:template match="/">
              <html>
              <body>
              <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
              <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#<xsl:value-of select='/event/color'/>">//something in this way i need use

                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><xsl:value-of select="/event/message"/></td>

                </tr>
              </table>
              </body>
              </html>
            </xsl:template>

            </xsl:stylesheet>
```

So I need to use inline style as xml element .
is there any solution for this and suggest me where I can learn xslt with xml and java

In similar way I need to add css file in that also I need to use this xml element of color value

Comment: <xml> <event><message>this is message</message><color>#666666</color></event> Xml is like this

Answer (score 0):

You can use an attribute value template `<tr bgcolor="{event/color}">`.